# Drag & Drop Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

Is it possible to perform drag & drop action via Espresso? I need to move one view down (in straight line) in order to accept some conditions in my automation test.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use GeneralSwipeAction to perform drag & drop.

```
public static ViewAction swipeUp() {  
return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_CENTER,  
    GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER);  
}
```

You can customize the location to meet your requirement as well.

Comment: swipeDown(), swipeUp() didn't work for me because I needed to move the circle to specific location.

Comment: Your code became useful to me in other case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Thats how I have done it. You have more access to what should happen with your view like that. But accepted answer perform drag&drop too.

```
  public static void drag(Instrumentation inst, float fromX, float toX, float fromY,
                            float toY, int stepCount) {
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        float y = fromY;
        float x = fromX;

        float yStep = (toY - fromY) / stepCount;
        float xStep = (toX - fromX) / stepCount;

        MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; ++i) {
            y += yStep;
            x += xStep;
            eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0);
            inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        }

        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
        inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        inst.waitForIdleSync();
    }
```

Comment: how do you call this method? I want to test something different but it can be a starting point. 

drag(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),0, 100, 0, 100, 20);

Comment: this call throws me a SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission. And this permission only for systems apps...

Comment: my question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759085/android-espresso-how-can-i-perform-onlongclick-and-slidedown-continued

Comment: supposing you want to drag a view onto another view, how would you get the destination view's coordinates in espresso?