# Android Espresso How do I perform touch events

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-touch-event

How can I test a view with simple touch events such as `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_MOVE`?

Answer (score 11):

You can easily send touch events. Use this view action:

```
public static ViewAction touchDownAndUp(final float x, final float y) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isDisplayed();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Send touch events.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, final View view) {
            // Get view absolute position
            int[] location = new int[2];
            view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            // Offset coordinates by view position
            float[] coordinates = new float[] { x + location[0], y + location[1] };
            float[] precision = new float[] { 1f, 1f };

            // Send down event, pause, and send up
            MotionEvent down = MotionEvents.sendDown(uiController, coordinates, precision).down;
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(200);
            MotionEvents.sendUp(uiController, down, coordinates);
        }
    };
}
```

And invoke it with:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view)).perform(touchDownAndUp(x, y));
```

Comment: This solution looks good, but how do you get x and y of a certain view?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way no Espresso matchers like `move(Gravity.LEFT, 40)` methods.

For some purposes like `ACTION_DOWN` you can use swiping methods like `swipeDown()`

Check Espresso.ViewActions Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html

For some you would need to modify existing methods like here: [Drag & Drop Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297442/drag-drop-espresso)

Also try to mix `Espresso` with other UI instrumentation frameworks like `Robotium` which already has some great matchers and function which Espresso doesn't have like `touch()` method or try another Google's framework called `uiatomator`.

Check: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Hope it will help