# Android Espresso, How can I perform onLongClick and slideDown continued?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I mean, I can perform the two actions sequentially but in the middle there is an `ACTION_UP` MotionEvent where I removed the OnTouchListener I'm using on the view

In my case I need to avoid trigger that event.

I have a sport field with players, one of the Use Cases is move a player after a longClick, the feature works well but I can’t reproduce the feature in the tests.

[image: No TouchListener until onLongClick]

Here is the code of the class I want to test, I tried to condensed all the relevant code associated to the question.

```java
public class FootballFieldLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {
    [...]
    public void addPlayer(FieldPlayer player) {
        final FieldPlayerView fpv = new FieldPlayerView(getContext(), player);
        addView(fpv);
        fpv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                v.setOnTouchListener(FootballFieldLayout.this);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
    [...]
    public float dX=NO_DELTA, dY=NO_DELTA;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(dX == NO_DELTA || dY == NO_DELTA){ setDelta(view, event); }
                view.animate()
                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                    .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.setOnTouchListener(null);
                resetDelta();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the test

```java
public class MoveOnLongClickActivityTest {
    [...]
    @Test
    public void playerCanBeMovedVerticallyAfterLongClick() throws InterruptedException {
        onView(withId(R.id.activity_field)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        View view = mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.test_player);

        float[] beginCoord = {view.getX(), view.getY()};
        onView(withId(R.id.test_player)).perform(longClick());
        onView(withId(R.id.test_player)).perform(swipeDown());
        float[] endCoord = {view.getX(), view.getY()};

        assertThat(beginCoord[1], not(equalTo(endCoord[1])));
    }
}
```

I always use the ViewActions of the framework or use a recipe from another person changing some things but I never tried to build a complex ViewAction and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I will explore a possible solution using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297442/drag-drop-espresso

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your comments under my question. Indeed I have faced the same problem at the moment (with INJECT_EVENTS permission and all my workarounds couldn't handle it). I used that code over half year ago and it worked for me without any problems.

I can propose other solution for you but I am not 100% sure it will work. Because I have created it like super fast now. I might have more time to look at it later.

Yet try this solution:

1. Try to write your own GeneralSwipeAction. Look at constructor:

   ```
   public GeneralSwipeAction(Swiper swiper, CoordinatesProvider startCoordinatesProvider, CoordinatesProvider endCoordinatesProvider, PrecisionDescriber precisionDescriber) {
       this.swiper = swiper;
       this.startCoordinatesProvider = startCoordinatesProvider;
       this.endCoordinatesProvider = endCoordinatesProvider;
       this.precisionDescriber = precisionDescriber;
   }
   ```

So position of x,y of start/end point are sent via CoordinatesProvider class. And it is an interface that returns array of floats. First float in array represent x and second one represent y.

2. Create your own class implementing Coordinates provider:

   ```
   import android.support.test.espresso.action.CoordinatesProvider;
   import android.view.View;

   public class CustomisableCoordinatesProvider implements CoordinatesProvider {

       private int x;
       private int y;

       public CustomisableCoordinatesProvider(int x, int y) {
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
       }

       @Override
       public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
           return new float[]{x,y};
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement your custom ViewAction that performs drag with usage of this CustomisableCoordinatesProvider:

   ```
   public static ViewAction drag(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
       return new GeneralSwipeAction(
           Swipe.FAST,
           new CustomisableCoordinatesProvider(startX, startY),
           new CustomisableCoordinatesProvider(endX, endY),
           Press.FINGER);
   }
   ```
4. And try to use it like this:

   ```
   onView(withId(R.id.test_player)).perform(drag(0, 100, 0, 100));
   ```

I haven't tested it. But it might work or help you by pointing to right direction. Try it and tell me if it works, I am curious myself :)

Comment: I'll check it out, but in my main question I want to recreate onlongclick and swipe without the ACTION_UP event. If your answer help me to achieve the problem I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Downvoted because (1) not tested and (2) does not work (running into security exceptions).