# Is there any test for drag and drop?

Tags: detox

I'm working on detox automation.
Started implementing the testcases for my mobile application. I need to do my dashboard customization.
My dashboard contains tiles, where a user can select a particular tile and get into more details.

**I want to move element1 to element2 in my dahboard. And even I want to delete a particular tile. Is there any functionality in detox for drag and drop ? If yes can any one help me out !**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Not currently supported by Detox, but it is open for pull requests. You can rely on: [Drag & Drop Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297442/drag-drop-espresso), at least for Android.